# uwsgi install in Debian 6 (Squeeze) wants to upgrade libc6 and initscripts

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

I'd like to install `uwsgi` on my Debian server. This package wants to upgrade some core packages:

- `libc6` from 2.11.3-3 (now, stable) -> 2.13-35
- `initscripts` from 2.88dsf-13.1+squeeze1 (now, stable) -> 2.88dsf-13.3

Can I do this safely, or is there a way to install this package without upgrading libc6? I have the following in the `/etc/apt/preferences` file:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 60

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50

Package: fabric
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to install, and mixing stable/testing is usually fine -- that's what dependencies are for, to make sure that everything gets the versions they need.

Gilles is incorrect: testing **does** get security updates.  See "[How is security handled for testing?](http://www.debian.org/security/faq#testing)" in the Debian FAQ for details.  You may need to adjust things like the `unattended-upgrades` configuration if you want them installed automatically.

**However**, your `/etc/apt/preferences` **will** cause problems with a mixed stable/testing system, because you've set the priorities way too high. Read the `apt_preferences(5)` man page carefully, particularly under "APT's Default Priority Assignments".  Basically, setting `Pin-Priority: 1001` for `stable`
is saying "install the version from `stable`, even if it's a downgrade of a package that was installed from `testing`".  Downgrading is generally an unsupported operation in `apt`, but even worse, this means that any time you try to install a newer version of a package like `libc` from `testing`, you'll constantly be running against problems where `apt` is trying its hardest to reinstall the old version.  That will quickly lead to the "conflicts and missing dependencies" that Gilles referred to.  On a **properly configured system** mixing distributions is fine.

The numbers you actually want to use are closer to:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 200

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 80

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

The key is that `stable` should be set between 100-500, and `testing` should be between 1 and 100.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination of `/etc/apt/preferences` and offering some options. I'll look into this

Comment: *"mixing stable/testing is usually fine"* -- the advice I usually hear from Debian developers directly contradicts this statement.  As soon as you try to install something from testing that requires a newer libc or glib, you're going to effectively drag in half of testing with whatever you're trying to install.  This is a bad idea; backporting packages is the recommended approach.

Comment: I still stand by my statement. Dragging in newer packages is acceptable to me, when the dependencies require it.  Timing matters quite a bit; for example, testing is currently in a freeze and is getting closer and closer to what will be in the next stable release. Anyway, the distinction between backports and pulling a package from testing is whether or not you think running testing is a good idea.  It does not change the fact that mixing stable and testing is safe (as safe as testing itself).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to install a package from the testing distribution on a stable installation. This almost never works, because the testing packages will pull in a lot of libraries and other packages from testing. You'll end up with a mixed stable/testing system, which is harder to maintain than pure testing because you'll encounter more conflicts and missing dependencies. Remember that testing doesn't get security updates as quickly as stable, it's a bad idea to use it on a server.

If you need one specific package that isn't available on stable, such as uwsgi, I recommend compiling it from source. Often, recompiling the source on stable will work; the minimum library dependencies in the package are generated based on the versions of the development packages you have installed. Alternatively, you may look for a [backport](http://backports-master.debian.org/): a package from testing that has been recompiled for stable.

In the case of uwsgi, there is no official backport but there is [an unofficial one](http://users.last.fm/~sven/squeeze-backports/). It appears that compiling from source requires [a few minor modifications and a libjansson backport](http://lists.debian.org/debian-backports/2012/07/msg00040.html). Remember that, whether you compile from source or use someone else's binary, you will not get security updates, so watch for security announcements upstream.

Comment: Seems like a good option to consider, if all fails. It seems doable especially with `uwsgi`. I do like to try the testing solution first, letting the package manager doing it's job. :)